# How to distribution count between rows SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

How to retrieve output with example :

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable 
(
     id varchar(55), 
     code int,
     count1 int,
     count2 int
);

INSERT INTO yourTable (id, code,count1,count2)
VALUES
    ('no-29', 12345, 4, 1),
    ('no-29', 32346, 4, 1)
```

always count1-count2 and results distribution between others rows with same id:
example : 4-1 = 3 and 3 distribution between 12345, 32346

I want too distribution  1,1 and 1,0 order by id,code(because 3 is odd and if even => 1,1 and 1,1 => countdistribute for codes is  2,2 )

Output :

```
id         code    countdistribute
----------------------------------
'no-29'    12345        2
'no-29'    32346        1
```

Comment: I really don't follow what you're trying to describe here. What is 2 rows, with the same value for `id`, have different values for `count1` and `count2`. What if `count2` has a greater value than `count1`?

Comment: if count2 greater than count1 mean 2-3 = -1 from first row and 0 for second row

Comment: What do `count1` and `count2` have to do with this question?

Comment: count1 and count2 is enter and exist count of stock

Comment: no solution?...